# Google Maps API v3 overlapping shapes opacity limit

Tags: google-maps

is there a way to limit the fill Opacity of overlapping shapes in google map ?
i am rendering polygons and circles that are overlapping and the map has become not visible.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fillOpacity` in the options object [PolygonOptions object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolygonOptions)

Comment: i have the fillOpacity style settings , but when there is overlapping of polygons , the opacity is the sum of all the individuals shapes. 4 polygons of fillOpacity 0.4 will be 1 ( 100 % )

Comment: that's just how opacity works. So what you ask is therefore not possible.

Comment: so the map is now completely blocked by the polygons , and there is nothing i can do ?

Comment: Correct. You could make the opacity of each Polygon less. But the way colours work everywhere is if you have two objects overlapping, each of 50% opacity, the result will be a coverage with 75% opacity. Starting with a lower opacity might help depending on how many you overlay. If you have a more complex requirement, you would have to somehow detect that the polygons are taking up the same space and then use setOptions to reduce the opacity of the polygons in that region. This is not a limitation of Google, it's how colours work.